# Proper way to initialize a const member of dynamically allocated struct

Tags: c

I have these 2 structs:

```
struct Params {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct Foo {
    const struct Params settings;
    int state;
};
```

The `settings` member is const as a hint that it should not be changed once a `struct Foo` has been created and initialized.

And I want to dynamically allocate this struct, e.g.

```
struct Foo * new_foo(void)
{
     struct Foo *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
     if (n) {
         n->settings.a = SETTING_A;
         n->settings.b = SETTING_B;
         ...
      }

      return n;
}
```

Now, this will not compile due to settings being const. What is a proper way to 
initialize such a struct in this manner? Or is it better to not declare the settings member as const?

Comment: It makes no sense to have a `const` copy of the struct, it makes a lot of sense to have a `const` pointer to an instance of the struct.

Comment: should `if (a)` be `if (n)`?

Comment: A const declaration in C asks the compiler to not let you assign to an object via that alias in the scope of the declaration. It doesn't acutally mean the object is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory is allocated (and thus, not constant), so it is legal to cast `const` away:

```
struct Foo * new_foo(void)
{
    struct Foo *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
    if (n) {
        struct Params *s = (void *)&n->settings;
        s->a = SETTING_A;
        s->b = SETTING_B;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Changed `if (a)` to `if (n)`, looked like a typo.

Comment: why do you cast to `(void *)` instead of `(struct Params *)`?

Comment: @mch, either would work, and I don't think either of them is better. `void *` is shorter.

Comment: Casting to `struct Params*` is better because it adds a little bit of extra type safety. In case you for example goofed up the declaration of `s`. Consider this: `int* ptr; ... int** pptr = (void*)ptr;`. Because void* is compatible with every other pointer type, you'll get no compiler error/warning even though the types aren't compatible.

Comment: @Lundin, I disagree, if you don't notice the wrong type in the declaration, why should you notice in the cast? Consider `int **pptr = (int **)ptr;` -- still not what was intended. Type-safety would mean to have a way of saying "the type of the RHS, just the `const` removed", which isn't possible, unfortunately.

Comment: @mafso Hence "little bit of..."  :)  Of course in the end, there is just so much the compiler can do to save the programmer from themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
struct Foo *new_foo(void)
{
    static struct Foo foo =
    {
        .settings =
        {
            .a = SETTING_A,
            .b = SETTING_B
        },
        .state = ...
    };

    struct Foo *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
    memcpy(n, &foo, sizeof *n);

    return n;
}
```

---

Here is another way to do it:

```
struct Foo *new_foo(void)
{
    static struct Params settings =
    {
        .a = SETTING_A,
        .b = SETTING_B
    };

    struct Foo *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
    memcpy((struct Params*)&n->settings, &settings, sizeof settings);
    n->state = ...;

    return n;
}
```